# incompatible types

Tags: java, types

I have looked at other examples of string parsing and thought I have the syntax correct.

I get an  error when I try to compile this,  incompatable types

```
String temp=date.split("/");  //parse date
```

any   suggestions

```
System.out.println("Enter the date in mm/dd/yyyy format. ");  //user input
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);                    //read input
String date=keyboard.next();                                //store input
String temp=date.split("/");  //parse date
int month=IntegerparseInt(temp[1]);
int day=IntegerparseInt(temp[0]);
int year=IntegerparseInt(temp[2]);
System.out.println(month);
System.out.println(day);    
System.out.println(year);
```

Comment: Please check the docs.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: String temp=date.split("/");  the slash is causing the error.  I dont understand why. The / delimiter is in quotes.

Answer (score 4):

`split` returns a `String array`, not a `String`.  You copied this code wrong, since in the next line you use `temp` as an array.